# struct pointer by using memory allocation

Tags: c, struct, malloc

i am stucked in that code
how can make memory allocation for that struct

```
typedef struct {
  int a, b, c, d;
} FourInts;


void fillArray(int* array, int len) {
  printf("Filling an array at address %p with %d "
         "values\n", array, len);
  for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
    array[i] = (i * 3) + 2;
    // assert() verifies that the given condition is true
    // and exits the program otherwise. This is just a
    // "sanity check" to make sure that the line of code
    // above is doing what we intend.
    assert(array[i] == ( (i * 3) + 2) );
  }
  printf("Done!\n");
}


/***********from here the problem *******/
struct FourInts *heap_struct_FourInts = (FourInts*) malloc(sizeof( FourInts) * 1);

  fillArray(heap_struct_FourInts->*a), 4);


  free(heap_struct_FourInts);
```

the compiler gives me that error

```
   arrays.c:222:43: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
   struct FourInts *heap_struct_FourInts = (FourInts*) malloc(sizeof( FourInts) * 1);
                                           ^
arrays.c:224:33: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
   fillArray(heap_struct_FourInts->a, 4);
                             ^
```

what is the error in the code for the struct and malloc ?

Comment: I believe the type of `heap_struct_FourInts` should be `FourInts*` not `struct FourInts*` but I don't know why that would cause the errors that are produced.

Comment: The warning comes from the fact, that you assign a pointer to `FourInts` to a pointer to `struct FourInts`—note, that they are distinct types the latter of which is declared at line 222. Your error message shows a line different from the line in your code. A typo? (Don't type, copy and paste).

Comment: You might want to use a cast in your call to fillArray so that it would be `fillArray((int *) heap_struct_FourInts, 4);`, since fillArray is declared as taking `(int*, int)` parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following function call is incorrect:

```
fillArray(heap_struct_FourInts->*a), 4);
```

`a` is an `int`, not a pointer to an `int`, so you cannot dereference it.  (Even if it was a pointer to an `int`, your syntax is incorrect).

Also, in your structure ...

```
typedef struct {
    int a, b, c, d;
} FourInts;
```

... you are not declaring an array of 4 `int`s, but four independent `int`s.  If you would like `a` to be an array of `int`s with a length of 4 you need to declare it like this:

```
typedef struct {
    int a[4], b, c, d;
} FourInts;
```

Now you can call you function like this:

```
FourInts *heap_struct_FourInts = malloc(sizeof(*heap_struct_FourInts);
fillArray(heap_struct_FourInts->a), 4);
```

The following is equivalent:

```
fillArray((*heap_struct_FourInts).a), 4);
```

Answer (score 1):

To fix the first warning drop the `struct` from the variable type since it is not a `struct`, but a `typedef` for a `struct` (thus, warning for type mismatch). As for the error, use `&heap_struct_FourInts->a` to pass the address of the very first int in your structure.

However, the code potentially invokes undefined behaviour as the `int`s need not be contiguous in memory. For example, a compiler could be configured to pad to 8 byte boundaries by default, in which case there would be 4 unused bytes after each `int` (assuming we're on a platform that has 4 byte `int`). Read up on `struct` padding for more information. That particular padding would be a very unlikely scenario, but it is something to keep in mind.

Comment: Sprechen Sie Englisch? ;-)

Comment: @Fiddling Bits Ich hoffe es ... :-)

Comment: To add to Alex's point, ALWAYS address a data type when using `structs` via the user-defined type you created (ie: as a complete struct), or by accessing its members. Alignment and padding issues will always bite you if you do otherwise.